# Use type synonym in type declaration mapping

Tags: haskell, type-families

I've implemented a map type type family like this

```
type family MapT (t :: * -> *) (e::[*]) 
type instance MapT t '[] = '[]
type instance MapT t (a ': as) = (t a) ': (MapT t as)
```

It works with a type constructor :

```
type MList  = MapT Maybe '[Int, String]
```

gives

```
'[Maybe Int, Maybe String]
```

However, I try

```
type M a = Maybe a
type MList' = MapT M '[Int, String]
```

It doesn't work.

I tried type family as well

```
type family M a
type instance M a = Maybe a
```

but It still doesn't work, saying

```
 `Type synonym `M` should have 1 argument.
```

Is there a way to solve this without having to create a new datatype (or new type) ?

Comment: In this particular case, you can still say `type M = Maybe` to make it work. But as Dominique says in his answer, there's no general type-level lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to solve this without having to create a new datatype (or newtype).  What you are looking for seems to be a type-level lambda (like you have in many formal Haskell-related calculi like System Fw and its extensions), but Haskell unfortunately does not have type-level lambdas.  Type synonyms may look like they could be used for this, but unfortunately, they must be fully-applied when they are mentioned.  You need to use a newtype or data type instead, as you mentioned yourself..